# Is it possible to build custom auth flow consisting multistep form that requires image upload, phone no. verification, etc. using React and Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, custom-authentication

I want to build a multistep registration Auth flow where these are the required steps and flow:

1. In the first step User verifies mobile number with otp.
2. In the second step User uploads image of some ID proof.
3. In the third step User fills some extra details such as name, email, address, etc.
4. Finally user submits the form.

Upon receiving the form details an Admin(having direct access to firebase console and firestore) manually checks the details , if they seem real he/she sends  a newly generated Id(can be email or phone no.) and Password (created by admin) to the User through email or sms with which he/she can finally login.

I know it is complicated and might not be possible with firebase but I still want some insight and answer to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: So basically what you want is to create a custom authentication powered by Firestore to store all the required data but that uses only custom logic instead of the standard Firebase auth, is this what you want to achieve? If so, it might be possible but you are not going to find this solution on Stack since you would have to develop it from scratch

Comment: Yeah, I switched to Node js , JWT , express to achieve this.